# Nginx static files caching get 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, static-files

I have multiple location blocks in nginx.conf with most of them direct to containers e.g. grafana, prometheus.

```
    location / {
        alias /opt/myapp-ui/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;
    }
    location /prometheus/ {
        proxy_pass http://my-prometheus-demo:9090/;
        auth_basic           "MY prom";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
    }

    location /grafana/ {
        proxy_pass http://my-grafana-demo:3000/;
        rewrite  ^/grafana/(.*)  /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

I want to cache all css and js files. I added the following location block

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    expires max;
}
```

But when i reach https://mysite/prometheus or grafana they show incomplete and in HTTP header live i see that those files are getting 404 so I dded another line so now it looks like this

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    expires max;
    proxy_pass http://my-grafana-demo:3000/;
}
```

Now /grafana works but /prometheus does not and I can't add another proxy_pass to that location. How can I make it work?